# What is the proper way to do multiple ZMQ publishers with IPC?

Tags: ipc, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have a ZeroMQ pub/sub architecture where in addition to EPGM, I want to be able to "broadcast" over IPC (thus avoiding sending messages off box when local pub/sub processes are present).

I've read on the internet (and found through experience) that multiple processes can't call bind on the same IPC endpoint (e.g. "ipc:///tmp/myipc.ipc"), but I've also read that it's possible to have multiple publishers on the same IPC endpoint.

With that said, what is the "proper" way to have multiple publishers on the same IPC endpoint if multiple bind calls just break things?

Comment: With some deeper digging, it seems that I'm supposed to call connect() with the extra publisher sockets. I've attempted this, but I'm finding that my publisher messages don't go out to the endpoint when I use the connect method. Is there perhaps some special ZMQ socket setting I'm missing?